# I'm trying to remove the data of a specific node (node 3) but it is not working, I need to know where the error in my code is

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to remove the data of a specific node (node 3) but it doesn't seem to be working, I need help to find where my error is that doesn't remove the data.

remove method :

```
private static void remove(int value) {
        LinearNode<Integer> current = head, previous = null;

        // Find the node storing value
        while (current != null) {

            if (current.getElement().intValue() == value) { // node storing value was found
                current = null; // Node deleted
                break;
            } else {
                previous = current;
                current = current.getNext();
            }
        }

    }
```

print method :

```
private static void printElements() {
        System.out.print("List of elements: ");
        LinearNode<Integer> current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.getElement());
            current = current.getNext();
            if (current != null)
                System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think that `current = null;` will delete the node. All it is doing is re-setting the reference of a *local* variable to null.

Comment: Well, any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: Yes: *change the state of the object*, don't change the reference held by a local variable. You need to change the next value of one of the items in the list.

Comment: such as,... `previous.setNext(current.getNext());` or some-such